# Create monorepo with frontend and backend applications (React.js/Nest.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, nest, monorepo

I was wondering if it is possible to create monorepo (keep it in one Github repository) with two projects - one frontend app made with React.js and the backend app with Nest.js. I thought I can use [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/) but it looks like it's only good for creating packages.

Comment: Lerna is for managing monorepos. Not sure why you think it's only for packages?

Comment: The examples in documentation only shows how to publish packages... so looks like I didn't understand Lerna correctly ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/), [TurboRepo](https://turbo.build/repo), etc. [This blog post](https://byteofdev.com/posts/lerna-vs-turbopack-rush) does a good job explaining comparisons between popular monorepo options. They come to a conclusion, but I'd suggest looking at the feature comparison and choose whichever best suits your project.